# FluentValidation for names

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following class

```
public class User 
{
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
}
```

And for that one I want to use a regex with fluent validation to be accepted just letters and whitespaces. As a regex might be a good example but I didn't find any implementation

And I created the following validator

```
    public class UserValidator:AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .NotEmpty()
            .NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please ensure that to set a value for {PropertyName}")
            .Must(BeValidName).WithMessage("Please ensure that to set a valid value for {PropertyName}")
            .Length(3, 30);

        private bool BeValidName(string name)
    {
        return name.All(Char.IsLetter);
    }
```

}

But I m going to search something better :D Do you guys have any idea ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of accepting only letters and spaces for the `Name` field using FluentValidation and Regex.

```
public class User
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .NotEmpty()
            .NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Matches(@"^[A-Za-z\s]*$").WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' should only contain letters.")
            .Length(3, 30);
    }
}
```

Validation Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex validators](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#regular-expression-validator)

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name).Matches("some regex here");
```